# WebAudio sounds from wave point

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Suppose that I make a simple canvas drawing app like this:

[image]

I now have a series of points. How can I feed them to some of the WebAudio objects (an oscillator or a sound make from a byte array or something) to actually generate and play a wave out of them (in this case a sine-like wave)? What is the theory behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data from your graph in an array, y, you can do something like

```
var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, y.length, context.sampleRate);
buffer.copyToChannel(y);
var src = context.createBufferSource();
src.buffer = buffer;
src.start()
```

You may need to set the sample rate in `context.createBuffer` to something other than `context.sampleRate`, depending on the data from your graph.

Comment: Wow, thanks. In what range should the values in the array be? What do they represent? I mean, should they be reduced to something like -1 / +1, they're frequency and hence in some 200 / 1000 range or what?

Comment: The values should be in the range -1 to +1.  These values should be the time samples of the waveform you want, not frequencies.